# Blender closes when using the scroll wheel

Tags: add-on, windows

I am running a Windows 8 and have recently installed Laplacian Lightning and Blender Source Tools, and have failed to import Mineways twice. My new problem is that I cannot touch the scroll wheel without Blender suddenly closing on me. No error messages, no laggy crashes. Just blankness.

I have no clue what is going on and I need Blender to start working again because I'm not happy with this.

HINT: it's Laplacian Lightning. Looks like there's a problem that can't be avoided. Not because of RAM but because of a possible bug which I don't know how to fix.

Comment: How much ram do you have?

Comment: I don't really know

Comment: To check how much ram you have, open task manager and it should show you. I have noticed that when I don't have enough ram, blender closes. Do you have multiple programs open at a time? Is your systems ram too low?? If you can tell me one of those, I can help.

Comment: If you reckon its one of the newly installed addons, try unchecking them in the user preferences and see if that helps at all? If not then it might be the best option to simply uninstall and reinstall blender? :)

Comment: well, none of the operators on the laplacian lightning addon are modal, and there are no references to any event which might be triggered by the mousewheel, so.. i'm not inclined to agree that the bug exists primarily in that addon.